# Why isnt meta content name working

Tags: html

I am making a simple website redirect page to redirect to twitter but have it as a web app on my iphone. It seems like the meta name tag dosent work or something, because the page has no title and i would like it to say twitter.Can anyone help me?  Sorry if im not using the correct terminology as i just got into html and im 15. thanks. Below is the code i have for my page, i have the meta tag in there but it seems like its not working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://bkenterprises.neocities.org/twitters.png" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://bkenterprises.neocities.org/twitters.png" />
      <meta http-equiv="Refresh" 
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.twitter.com" /> 
      <meta content="name="Twitter" />
      </head>
    <html>
```

Comment: These an unclosed tag and some extra quotes

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming

```
<meta content="name="Twitter" />
```

should be:

```
<meta content-name="Twitter" />
```

or:

```
<meta content="Twitter" name="Idontknow" />
```

I'm also assuming `<meta http-equiv="Refresh"` is just a cut 'n paste error. If not, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag is used to provide data about your HTML file, what you want to use is

```
<title></title> This has to be within your head tags, they are used like this
<title>Example</title> This will create the title on your page tab, for extra touches you can also use <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Your link"/> If you want the small image next to your title
```